# What's the best way to create stitches on clothing?

Tags: modeling, texturing

I want to create a gambeson to be used inside a game engine, but I'm always ending on the same problem. It's creating the stitching on clothing that I find very difficult. The modelling part is easy to do, it's a simple shape, the problem is creating the stitches on it.

Here are some references of what I want to achieve:

[image]

[image]
[image]

How can you achieve this stitching effect on clothing, in this case a gambeson, in a way that can be used in a game engine.

Comment: can you just fake it with bump or normal map?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to do in the end. But how do I make the stitching? Do I model it, do I texture it? I first need to have stitches before I can bake anything.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe create a pattern like that and bake it, you'll have both the stitches and the padded effect. It will need a layer of sculpt though, to add all the folds:

[image]

Comment: Hmm...could I place the stitches trough a curve to fit the mesh?

Comment: maybe bake the heights, then unwrap the coat and put the UVs over the b&w pattern? I'm not sure why you would need a curve

Comment: I was thinking on doing it with modelling. It's just how I saw it people doing in Zbrush. But that could work.

Comment: modeling it will be painful, just bake the normals (or the heights), what you should model though is all the folds afterwards

Comment: I don't think I understood what it is you said. I tried to do what you advised, but I'm not getting any good results this way.

Comment: you need to correctly unwrap your cloth and put the UV island over the normal map image, maybe show what you've done so far?